# difference between cmd and entrypoint in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and have a simple question about the Dockerfile. We can write entrypoint and CMD in Dockerfile. Seems that ENTRYPOINT is executed during creating the container. And CMD is executed during starting the container. Is this true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly:

[`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) configures a container that will run as an executable.
So it is *always* executed (or the default `/bin/sh -c` is).

```
ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"] (exec form, preferred)
ENTRYPOINT command param1 param2 (shell form)
```

> Command line arguments to `docker run <image>` will be appended after all elements in an exec form `ENTRYPOINT`, and will override all elements specified using CMD.
>
> The shell form prevents any `CMD` or run command line arguments from being used, but has the disadvantage that your `ENTRYPOINT` will be started as a subcommand of `/bin/sh -c`, which does not pass signals.
>   This means that the executable will not be the container’s PID 1 - and will not receive Unix signals - so your executable will not receive a SIGTERM from `docker stop <container>`.

You can view [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) as parameters for the `ENTRYPOINT`.
if there is no entrypoint (the default command is "`/bin/sh -c`"), `CMD` can include an executable.
If `ENTRYPOINT` already runs an executable, then the CMD arguments are parameters to this command (if `docker run` is used without additional parameters).

---

With [`docker start`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/), as mentioned in [issue 1437](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1437#issuecomment-22339720), the `ENTRYPOINT` is executed, but only with parameters from `CMD` (so `CMD` is used, but you cannot override it with parameters of your own on the command-line).
IF you want to use CMD, you need `docker run`, not `docker start`.

There actually is a recent PR in progress ([PR 19746](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19746)) which allows for the docker start command to take an optional `--cmd` (`-c`) flag to specify the cmd to use instead of the default one from cmd/entrypoint.

---

The [Official Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) now has a section "[Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact)":

> - Dockerfile should specify at least one of `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` commands.
> - `ENTRYPOINT` should be defined when using the container as an executable.
> - `CMD` should be used as a way of defining default arguments for an `ENTRYPOINT` command or for executing an ad-hoc command in a container.
> - `CMD` will be overridden when running the container with alternative arguments.

That means, if your Dockerfile includes:

> - **No `CMD`**:
>
>   - if No `ENTRYPOINT`: error, not allowed
>   - `ENTRYPOINT exec_entry p1_entry` means `/bin/sh -c exec_entry p1_entry`
>   - `ENTRYPOINT ["exec_entry", "p1_entry"]` means `exec_entry p1_entry`
> - **`CMD ["exec_cmd", "p1_cmd"]`** (one command, one parameter)
>
>   - if No `ENTRYPOINT`: `exec_cmd p1_cmd`,
>   - `ENTRYPOINT exec_entry p1_entry` means `/bin/sh -c exec_entry p1_entry exec_cmd p1_cmd`
>   - `ENTRYPOINT ["exec_entry", "p1_entry"]` means `exec_entry p1_entry exec_cmd p1_cmd`
> - **`CMD ["p1_cmd", "p2_cmd"]`**
>
>   - if No `ENTRYPOINT`: `p1_cmd p2_cmd`
>   - `ENTRYPOINT exec_entry p1_entry` means `/bin/sh -c exec_entry p1_entry p1_cmd p2_cmd` (good)
>   - `ENTRYPOINT [“exec_entry”, “p1_entry”]` means `exec_entry p1_entry p1_cmd p2_cmd`
> - **`CMD exec_cmd p1_cmd`**:
>
>   - if No `ENTRYPOINT`: `/bin/sh -c exec_cmd p1_cmd`
>   - `ENTRYPOINT exec_entry p1_entry` means `/bin/sh -c exec_entry p1_entry /bin/sh -c exec_cmd p1_cmd`
>   - `ENTRYPOINT [“exec_entry”, “p1_entry”]` means `exec_entry p1_entry /bin/sh -c exec_cmd p1_cmd`

Comment: what if docker start?

Comment: @richard I have edited the answer to include docker start.

Comment: thanks a lot, I am trying to practice to find the difference.

Comment: as an example, look at https://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/nethogs/, it starts nethogs on wlan0 (as ENTRYPOINT is `nethogs` and CMD is `wlan0` if you start it with `docker run -it k3ck3c/captvty`, and if you want to monitor, say eth0, you will do `docker run -it k3ck3c/captvty eth0` Maybe an example like this one explains it more

Comment: Thanks! I need to print this