# Why does the name column of the docker ps -a always different

Tags: docker, docker-image

I was just playing around with docker!!

**Ran ps command -a option**

```
docker run -a
C:\Users\sarkan1>docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
3d6db385321c        busybox:1.24        "sleep 1000"        26 seconds ago      Up 24 seconds                                   lucid_ramanujan
e6acd65398b2        hello-world         "/hello"            43 minutes ago      Exited (0) 43 minutes ago                       nifty_brattain
c5576137580d        hello-world         "/hello"            4 days ago          Exited (0) 4 days ago                           dreamy_aryabhata
2594fbf1fa82        hello-world         "/hello"            4 days ago          Exited (0) 4 days ago                           nostalgic_hopper
c0102bc64c45        hello-world         "/hello"            4 days ago          Exited (0) 4 days ago                           vibrant_khorana
c4af79ea96e9        hello-world         "/hello"            4 days ago          Exited (0) 4 days ago                           cranky_heyrovsky
```

Questions :

1. Why did I get the values in the names column always different? I ran the same container I guess!!
2. What is command column? Does the slash before the hello (`/hello`) have  any significance?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unless you launch a container specifying its name ([docker run --name](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#container-identification)), docker will generate one for you.
That is easier than referencing said container with its ID.

You can then make docker commands with its (generated) name instead.

See more at "[How does Docker generate default container names?](https://frightanic.com/computers/docker-default-container-names/)".
(and the source code: [moby/moby `pkg/namesgenerator/names-generator.go`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/pkg/namesgenerator/names-generator.go))

The command column is the full command executed by the container: once this command stops, the container stops.
That command is specified in the docker image, and is a combination of:

- [Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)
- [Dockerfile `CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

(See "[difference between cmd and entrypoint in dockefile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35453524/6309)")

Comment: Great !! I found the link shared by you interesting and relevant!! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Basically they are random container names generated!! The left and right parts of the names are hardcoded and can be found in

https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/pkg/namesgenerator/names-generator.go

Docker engine generates it if default name is not provided when you create a new docker container.