# How do I stop this error from returning after running Lando start or rebuild on a drupal template project

Tags: docker, ubuntu, drupal, composer-php, lando

I get this error everytime I run `lando start` or `lando rebuild` on a project I've installed from a `drupal 8` template.

I've redone `composer create project`, `composer install`, `lando destroy`, `lando rebuild` etc. None have worked. I've also checked to see if I have the most recent versions of `lando`, `composer`, & `docker`. So I'm not sure if this is an issue with something in the code or something else entirely.

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"cd\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
error: Looks like one of your build steps failed! with Error
    at module.exports.sh.Promise.try.then (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/shell.js:0:0)
From previous event:
    at Shell.sh (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/shell.js:0:0)
    at Object.exports.dc (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/bootstrap.js:0:0)
    at compose (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/bootstrap.js:0:0)
    at exports.run.Promise.each.docker.isRunning.then.then (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/router.js:0:0)
From previous event:
    at exports.run.Promise.each.datum (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/router.js:0:0)
    at runCallback (timers.js:696:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:667:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:649:5)
From previous event:
    at Object.exports.run (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/router.js:0:0)
    at run (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/engine.js:0:0)
    at exports.eventWrapper.daemon.up.then.then (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/router.js:0:0)
From previous event:
    at Object.exports.eventWrapper (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/router.js:0:0)
    at Engine.module.exports.constructor.engineCmd (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/engine.js:0:0)
    at Engine.run (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/engine.js:0:0)
    at Object.exports.runBuild (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/plugins/lando-services/lib/utils.js:0:0)
    at AsyncEvents.module.exports.app.events.on.app.events.on (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/plugins/lando-services/app.js:0:0)
    at AsyncEvents.handle (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/events.js:0:0)
    at emit.Promise.each.fn (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/events.js:0:0)
From previous event:
    at AsyncEvents.emit (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/events.js:0:0)
    at module.exports.start.initAndReport.then.then.then (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/app.js:0:0)
From previous event:
    at App.start (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/app.js:0:0)
    at Object.exports.appToggle (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/plugins/lando-core/lib/utils.js:0:0)
    at Object.run (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/plugins/lando-core/tasks/start.js:0:0)
    at module.exports.parseToYargs.checkForUpdates.then.lando.bootstrap.then.lando.events.emit.then.then.then.then.then (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/cli.js:0:0)
From previous event:
    at module.exports.parseToYargs.checkForUpdates.then.lando.bootstrap.then.lando (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/cli.js:0:0)
From previous event:
    at module.exports.parseToYargs.checkForUpdates.then (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/cli.js:0:0)
    at runCallback (timers.js:696:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:667:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:649:5)
From previous event:
    at Object.handler (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/cli.js:0:0)
    at Object.runCommand (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/node_modules/yargs/lib/command.js:238:44)
    at Object.parseArgs [as _parseArgs] (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1063:30)
    at Function.get [as argv] (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1004:21)
    at Cli.run (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/lib/cli.js:0:0)
    at lando.bootstrap.then.lando.getApp.init.then (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/bin/lando.js:0:0)
From previous event:
    at lando.bootstrap.then.lando (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/bin/lando.js:0:0)
    at runCallback (timers.js:696:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:667:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:649:5)
From previous event:
    at Object.<anonymous> (/snapshot/lando/build/cli/bin/lando.js:0:0)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1254:22)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:549:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:541:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1309:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:274:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:608:3)
warn: This **MAY** prevent your app from working
warn: Check for errors above, fix them, and try again
```

I receive working urls despite this error.

edit: added docker-compose.yml file ...

```
version: '2'

services:
  solr:
    image: solr:8.1
    ports:
     - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - data:/opt/solr/server/solr/d8
      - ./tests/solr-conf/8.x:/solr-conf/conf
    entrypoint:
      - docker-entrypoint.sh
      - solr-precreate
      - d8
      - /solr-conf
volumes:
  data:
```

Comment: duplicated by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001082/oci-runtime-exec-failed-exec-failed-executable-file-not-found-in-path/48835704. Following should also be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35452760/difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-dockefile/35453524

Comment: I'm using lando as a wrapper for composer and docker so looking through that didn't really give me an idea of what I can do to fix it.

Comment: `starting container process caused "exec: \"cd\"` - what it means that your `Dockerfile` has a `CMD` or `Entrypoint` statement for which the `PATH` of probably `cd` - very basic bash can not be found. Try sharing the `Dockerfile`

Comment: it looks like you're executing `bash` (`cd` command) in javascript ... If you add your `Dockerfile`, I will change the vote.

Comment: Sure, which dockerfile would you like me to post? In the project files there is 'docker-compose.yml'  and a 'docker.yml' file.

Comment: Ok so I added docker-compose.yml because I realized the project didn't have a Dockerfile but rather used an image from solr.

Comment: ok, so actually the issue comes when it runs `docker-entrypoint.sh solr-precreate d8  /solr-conf`. Let me test and come back.

Answer (score 0):

Looks Ok to me:

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "stackoverflow-57693461_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "stackoverflow-57693461_data" with default driver
Pulling solr (solr:8.1)...
8.1: Pulling from library/solr
9cc2ad81d40d: Pull complete
(...)
f059ff7111be: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:6731556f68c4b8df2b1681f5a021014e9e1378c8a658ff90aa41a5071223e743
Status: Downloaded newer image for solr:8.1
Creating stackoverflow-57693461_solr_1 ... done
Attaching to stackoverflow-57693461_solr_1
solr_1  | Executing /opt/docker-solr/scripts/solr-precreate d8 /solr-conf
solr_1  | Executing /opt/docker-solr/scripts/precreate-core d8 /solr-conf
solr_1  | Created d8
solr_1  | Starting Solr 8.1.1
solr_1  | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve shared memory. (error = 1)
solr_1  | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve shared memory. (error = 1)
solr_1  | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Failed to reserve shared memory. (error = 1)
solr_1  | 2019-08-30 19:28:43.820 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.u.log Logging initialized @912ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
(...)
solr_1  | 2019-08-30 19:28:45.789 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.AbstractConnector Started ServerConnector@1937eaff{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1, h2c]}{0.0.0.0:8983}
solr_1  | 2019-08-30 19:28:45.789 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.Server Started @2883ms
```

How are you executing the container? through `lando start`, I presume ? I wonder what is in `docker.yaml`. This `docker-compose.yaml` is straight-forward. I don'
t see any issue with it.

Comment: This was in my docker.yml file : 

`# Drupal4Docker example
dev:
  root: /var/www/html
  extra-options: docker-compose exec --user=82 php
  type: container`